# Getting garbage after calling property in another smart contract.

Tags: solidity, tokens

I'm using liquid democracy contract from  https://www.ethereum.org/dao

This is the relationship.

Shareholder Association has this definition when pointing to liquid democracy contract.

```
contract token {
    mapping (address => uint256) public voteWeight;
    uint public numberOfDelegationRounds;

    function balanceOf(address member) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        if (numberOfDelegationRounds < 3)
            return 0;
        else
            return this.voteWeight(member);
    }
}
```

then liquid democracy contract points to token contract and defines its connection as this.

```
contract token {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
}
```

The line in Shareholder Association below returns garbage data.

```
uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter);
```

something like this which is big number.

> 76181730938387481504298103224485865201289833135200371729261377095349320967255

I had to combine logic from those contracts into one for it to work.
I'm not using token contract anymore for this though as my contracts use 1 token per user and I have just internally implemented it giving each user one vote.

Of course I would like to reuse the code and be able to execute this idea like shown on the Ethereum site.